# Can't properly attach pdf made with nodejs PDFKit to email sent through Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, pdf, nodemailer, node-pdfkit

I'm having problems attaching a pdf that i made with pdfkit(node) to an email that gets sent through nodemailer and the Sendgrid API.  Email works fine.  The pdf that is produced to disk is fine, but the pdf on attachment keeps coming up corrupted and unreadable.  I've tried many different variations, and researched through google, but i'm not sure how to get this to work.

the code that creates the pdf:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

doc = new PDFDocument({
    size: 'letter'
});

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./public/img/test.pdf'));

doc.text('my text')

doc.end();
```

my nodemailer code:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');
var options = {
    auth: {
        api_key: process.env.SENDGRID_API
    }
}
var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

var email = {
        to: 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com',
        from: 'example@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Please work',
        text: 'Check out this pdf',
        attachments: [{
            filename: 'test.pdf',
            path: './public/img/test.pdf',
            contentType: 'application/pdf'
        }]
    };

mailer.sendMail(email, function(err, res){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(res);
});
```

Am i missing something?  Instead of writing the pdf to disk, I also read that another way to do this was to stream the pdf directly to my email.  Except i'm not sure how to do this either.

Answer (score 3):

I have been experiencing the same problem. I noticed that the file I got in my mailbox was missing the last few lines, making a corrupted file.

The reason for this is that the filesystem `fs` doesn't have the time to finish writing the pdf that the mail is already sent with Nodemailer.

You need to wait for the "finish" event on the `fs` writestream. This is what I did :

```
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  const fileName = 'aPdfFile.pdf';
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
  doc.pipe(writeStream);

  // do something with your pdf document ...

  doc.end();
  writeStream.on('finish', function () {
    // call the callback function or in my case resolve the Promise.
    resolve(fileName);
  });
```